# opencv- Getting std::length_error' what(): vector::_M_fill_insert when computing HOG features from 25*125 eye image

Tags: opencv

When I am calculating the HOG features of eye image of size 25*125. then getting the error message terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  vector::_M_fill_insert

```
HOGDescriptor hog;
vector<float> ders;
vector<Point>locs;
hog.compute(img,ders,Size(4,4),Size(0,0),locs);
Mat Hogfeat;
Hogfeat.create(ders.size(),1,CV_32FC1);

for(int i=0;i<ders.size();i++)
{
Hogfeat.at<float>(i,0)=ders.at(i);

}
```

Can any one tell me the solution?

Answer (score 4):

One side of the image is smaller than the descriptor and therefore the computation fails.

If I use the following line, the computation works for me:

```
hog.compute(img,ders,Size(3,3),Size(0,0),locs);
```

The size of blocks is 8. So `3 * 8 = 24 <= 25` but  `4 * 8 = 32 > 25`.

The solution depends on what exactly you want to achieve and which compromise you are willing to make. 
You could just use the smaller descriptor which might lead to some loss in descriptiveness for other images. Or you could scale or pad the images that are too small which will probably make their descriptors less useful but won't affect the others.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and I solved it by resizing the image to (64 x 128) or larger; any size smaller than this will return that error. so you should do

`resize(img, dst, Size(64, 128))¶`

before you call `hog.compute(....)`